# How do I Enable Auto complete option in combo box by programming in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am dynamically adding combo box to a form but i am not able to enable its auto-complete option.
what property should we use to enable its auto complete option.

I Tried it as

```
Set DesiredControl = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Combobox.1", Visible)
DesiredControl.Left = 350
DesiredControl.RowSource = "Interface!xfd2:xfd6"
DesiredControl.Top = 20 * i
DesiredControl.Width = 175
DesiredControl.Height = 19
'DesiredControl.AutoComplete = enable
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Uncomment the last line?

Comment: It gives me run time error 438  Object doesn't support this property.

Comment: Maybe you mean MatchEntry option? `DesiredControl.MatchEntry`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Review the available properties in the VBE, and you will see some like:

`MatchEntry` and `MatchEntryRequired`.

[image]

You will want to use:

`MatchEntry = 1 'fmMatchEntryComplete`

And probably in conjunction with:

`MatchEntryRequired = True`